# changing x-axis of FFT plot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, fft

This is my first post here and im new to coding just to let you know.

i want to make a fft analysis of a time-series dataset spanning one year with datapoints in 15 minute intervals. The dataset I use represents the state of charge of a battery in %. I want to see the different loading cycles (horly, weekly, monthly).

I watched some youtube videos and applied the code of this video to my own data: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su9YSmwZmPg

here is my code:

```
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq, ifft 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

# setup domain
# number of points (15 min intervals within 1 year)
nl = 34943

# lengt of watched domain 
# 1 year in hours
lx    = 34943/4

# creating x-achsis
x = np.linspace(0, lx, nl)

# full signal
# dataset of different values troughout the year
y = np.array(df['SOC_batt'])

# creating nexessary frequencies
freqs = fftfreq(nl)

# splitting frequencies in half 
mask = freqs > 0 

# fft values
fft_vals = fft(y)

# true theoretical fft
fft_theo = 2.0*np.abs(fft_vals/nl)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('original data')
plt.plot(x, y, color='xkcd:salmon')

plt.figure(2)
# fft processed
plt.plot(freqs[mask], fft_theo[mask], label='true fft values')
plt.title('true fft values')
mpld3.display()`
```

these are the plots i get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMDto.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ja4T.png)

I zoomed in the fft graph and got these x values from the peaks:

```
# first peack of 4 at 0.01041
# second peak of 5 at 0.02083
# third peack of 1.1 at 0.03125
```

how can i translate these into more meaningful values regarding im dealing with a whole year of data?
Im not sure how to include data in the post I hope my problem is still understandable though.

thanks in advance

Comment: Resource for learning: https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/

Comment: I already found that but it deals with functions rather than data...